# IIS FTP Server on Windows 2008 R2 Standard - Can only logon using administrator user/pass?

Tags: ftp, authentication, iis-7.5

I've setup a FTP server in IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard and enabled `Basic Authentication`. I have a *basic* user ("Ropstah") on the server which is in the `Users` and `Some Custom` groups. I've allowed the `Some Custom` group read/write access on the FTP folder.

Now when I connect to the server using "Ropstah" I get the following error:

> 530 User cannot login

**Why is this? (I am able to login to the FTP using the administrator account though...)**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

## Set in IIS

[image]

## Set in Windows Explorer:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a basic user ("Ropstah") on the server which is in the Users and Some Custom groups. I've allowed the Some Custom group read/write access on the FTP folder.

Where have you configured this? Setting it in the IIS FTP settings is only one step. You also need to give that group appropriate permissions on the NTFS ACLs for the FTP directory(ies) on the server. You'll probably want to give Modify in most cases.

Comment: I've added the user group to the folder through windows explorer...

Comment: I even tried adding "Full Control" for the specified user group, however still it doesn't work...

Comment: Have you also added that group in the FTP Authorization settings in IIS?

Comment: Yes... Please see the attached screenshots.

Comment: And you've removed anonymous access from the FTP console, leaving only basic?

Comment: Yes... I chose only `Basic` when creating the FTP server (i re-created it when this issue came up)

Comment: I tried logging in from the server (using the command prompt) and that gave a better error message. The user password seemed to have expired in the previous 15 minutes (aargh). Thanks for thinking along anyway!